# How can I simplify this sentence?

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis, passive-voice, active-voice

"GHWC has solutions that address the root causes of common problems."

"has solutions that" seems bulky and incorrect.  I feel like it could be more active voice.

Comment: It may well be a platitude that lacks clear meaning. But it is grammatically succinct and correct. It is difficult to comment further without more background as to what one intends to say.

Comment: Could you add some more information of the context in which this phrase will be used?

Comment: Yes, I can.  This is a tagline for GWHS's website.  The tagline is to address the common problems of their industry by saying that GWHS is experienced and aware of the proper solutions. 

I suppose I was concerned about the grammar.  The language is verbose and not refined.  For a generica marketing message, I feel it could be more succinct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could theoretically replace the **`has`** and **`that`** with a possessive GHWC, giving the result

> GWHC's solutions address the root causes of common problems

Answer (score 3):

It's not particularly clear what GHWC is, but depending on its level of agency it might be able to "address problems" rather than have solutions to problems.

"GHWC addresses the root causes of common problems."

or

"Many GHWC projects/employees/corollaries/statements address the root causes of common problems."

Comment: It might be necessary to keep the **`Solutions`** part present, we'll have to see what the OP says

Comment: *Solves* in stead of *addresses*

Comment: It is necessary to have solutions present.  We are presenting their "solutions" as the product or value of their organization.

Thanks for your input. I like the versions presented!

Answer (score 0):

GHWC solves common problems by nipping them in the bud.

> This resorts to a cliché, but gets to the point quickly.